# How can I construct a SQL to find the MAX of products in different date and time for each one?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

Please I need a SQL to find the MAX of QNTT for each product and know the date and hour.

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| Product   |  QNTT  |   date    |    hour   |
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|       AAA |     31 | 28-nov-18 |     09    |
|       AAA |     21 | 28-nov-18 |     10    |
|       AAA |     52 | 28-nov-18 |     11    |
|       AAA |     11 | 28-nov-18 |     12    |
|       AAA |     15 | 29-nov-18 |     09    |
|       AAA |     19 | 29-nov-18 |     10    |
|       AAA |     22 | 29-nov-18 |     11    |
|       AAA |     33 | 29-nov-18 |     12    |
|       AAA |     55 | 30-nov-18 |     09    |
|       AAA |     42 | 30-nov-18 |     10    |
|       AAA |     31 | 30-nov-18 |     11    |
|       AAA |     21 | 30-nov-18 |     12    |
|       BBB |     31 | 28-nov-18 |     09    |
|       BBB |     21 | 28-nov-18 |     10    |
|       BBB |     12 | 28-nov-18 |     11    |
|       BBB |     58 | 28-nov-18 |     12    |
|       BBB |     15 | 29-nov-18 |     09    |
|       BBB |     19 | 29-nov-18 |     10    |
|       BBB |     22 | 29-nov-18 |     11    |
|       BBB |     33 | 29-nov-18 |     12    |
|       BBB |     43 | 30-nov-18 |     09    |
|       BBB |     42 | 30-nov-18 |     10    |
|       BBB |     51 | 30-nov-18 |     11    |
|       BBB |     21 | 30-nov-18 |     12    |
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Answer of SQL that I want are both MAX(QNTT) of products:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| Product   |  QNTT  |   date    |    hour   |
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|       AAA |     55 | 30-nov-18 |     09    |
|       BBB |     58 | 28-nov-18 |     12    |
+-----------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

I can find the result with out time and date:

```
SELECT
    Product, max(QNTT)
FROM
    TABLE 
WHERE  
    Month(DATE) = 11 AND YEAR(DATE) = 2018 
AND
    Product <> 'AAAB' 
AND
    Substr(Product, 1, 3) IN ('AAA','BBB') 
AND
    hour<= 18 
AND
    Day(DATE) > 13   
GROUP BY
    Product  
ORDER BY
    Product, QNTT DESC
```

but I need the Date and Hour to know when were the max number for each on the month.

Comment: One option is to `join` the results of your existing query back to the original table, joining on the product and max quantity...

Comment: Consider storing date and time as a single entity

Comment: I added the [tag:greatest-n-per-group] tag. This type of question has been answered many times, please follow the tag for example answers.

Comment: As @sgeddes mentioned, you can join again to the original table, someting like this: `SELECT *  FROM table INNER JOIN (<here will go your current query>) AS newTable ON newTable.Product = table.Product AND newTable.maxQNTT = table.QNTT`. Where `maxQNTT` will be an alias for `max(QNTT)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `subquery` with `group by Product` as :

```
select *
  from tab 
 where ( Product, QNTT ) in
(select Product, max(QNTT)
   from tab
  group by Product ) t
```

Comment: Thank you all, for your help, this subquery solve my problem.